# Can anybody explain me the actual structure of an Dictionary in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm new to iPhone and i know about the primitive data structure in C like array and all but in objective c there is dictionary,i know that it is having a key value pair structure we can access values from equivalent keys   and mutable dictionary is dynamic and all.I mean the basic structure i am aware about, but when we have to prefer dictionary?,what are the possible manipulation we can do in dictionary,how optimized it is?.
Any help appreciated in advance.

Comment: An NSDictionary is a hash map. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashmap

Comment: `NSDictionary` is not a HashMap but [key-value pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_pair).`NSSet` is the Objective-C version of a HashMap

Comment: Isn't the NSSet the Obj-C version of HashSet? That would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSDictionary` is known more generally as an **Associative Array**.

See the following Wikipedia article for a full explanation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

You would use a dictionary rather than an array where you need to refer to an object by (for example) a name, rather than its position (index) in a list.

Answer (score 0):

partial answer:

an `NSDictionary` is a `CFDictionary`. to see the implementation of an earlier version of `CFDictionary`, apple's hosted a library called CF-Lite. reading the source may answer some questions about the type and its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Nsdictionary is like java dictionary. in this you add object for a particular  key and fetch this data.
 if u r new in objective c please go to this link is good for u.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Essentials